# Last column is too far apart, how do I get equal spacing?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Marginal Effects of Multinomial Logit}
\begin{tabular}{rccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 1     & 2&    3 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{A} & 0.039*** & -0.005*** & -0.021*** \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & (0.011) & (0.010) & (0.009) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -0.033*** & 0.007*** & 0.013*** \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & (0.012) & (0.011) & (0.010) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 0.056*** & 0.016*** & -0.045*** \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & (0.005) & (0.004) & (0.007) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{D} & -0.013*** & -0.007*** & 0.006*** \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & (0.007) & (0.006) & (0.006) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{E} & 0.006*** & -0.001*** & -0.023*** \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.002) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{F} & 0.010*** & -0.015*** & -0.058*** \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & (0.062) & (0.058) & (0.043) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{G} & -0.027*** & -0.005*** & 0.029*** \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & (0.024) & (0.021) & (0.018) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{H} & 0.029*** & 0.077*** & -0.022*** \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & (0.074) & (0.068) & ..0520676 \\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Standard errors in parentheses.   *p $<$ 0.10,    **p $<$ 
 0.05,     ***p $<$ 0.01} \\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
 \end{table}%
```

Comment: Last row in your table si to long. You need to broke it into two lines. For what you doing, see, if `threeparttable` and `siunitx` packages can improve your table. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Could you please make MWE from your code? To help others in the future if there are certain packages nedded.

Comment: A sidenote: Please use the correct minus symbol for negative numbers, not hyphens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually add spacing between the columns with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{30pt}` right before your table. `30pt` worked for me but you should consider **@Zarko's** comment to splitting the last line to something like:

- **Manually adding spaces**
  [image]

  `\multicolumn{4}{c}{Standard errors in parentheses.}   \\

  \multicolumn{4}{c}{*p $<$ 0.10, **p $<$     0.05,     ***p $<$ 0.01}`
- **Splitting the last row**

[image]

Comment: Could you please make MWE from your code? To help others in the future if there are certain packages nedded.

Answer (score 6):

I would design your tables like this:

[image]

For this I put in preamble

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
```

and for table use `threeparttable` environments, `S` column types, which enable number align at decimal point and in comparison with your code snippet remove all `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` (which are surplus):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Marginal Effects of Multinomial Logit}
    \label{tab:addlabel}
\begin{tabular}{r *{3}{S[table-format=-1.3,
                         input-symbols={( )},
                         table-space-text-post={***},
                        ]}
                }
    \toprule
    &   {1}             &   {2}             &   {3}             \\
    \midrule
A   & 0.039\tnote{***}  & -0.005\tnote{***} & -0.021\tnote{***} \\
    & (0.011)           & (0.010)           & (0.009)           \\
B   & -0.033\tnote{***} & 0.007\tnote{***}  & 0.013\tnote{***}  \\
    & (0.012)           & (0.011)           & (0.010)           \\
C   & 0.056\tnote{***}  & 0.016\tnote{***}  & -0.045\tnote{***} \\
    & (0.005)           & (0.004)           & (0.007)           \\
D   & -0.013\tnote{***} & -0.007\tnote{***} & 0.006\tnote{***}  \\
    & (0.007)           & (0.006)           & (0.006)           \\
E   & 0.006\tnote{***}  & -0.001\tnote{***} & -0.023\tnote{***} \\
    & (0.003)           & (0.002)           & (0.002)           \\
F   & 0.010\tnote{***}  & -0.015\tnote{***} & -0.058\tnote{***} \\
    & (0.062)           & (0.058)           & (0.043)           \\
G   & -0.027\tnote{***} & -0.005\tnote{***} & 0.029\tnote{***}  \\
    & (0.024)           & (0.021)           & (0.018)           \\
H   & 0.029\tnote{***}  & 0.077\tnote{***}  & -0.022\tnote{***} \\
    & (0.074)           & (0.068)           & (0.052)           \\
    \midrule[0.6pt]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Standard errors in parentheses.}             \\
\end{tabular}%    
\begin{tablenotes}[para]\footnotesize
    \item[*]    $p < 0.10$,
    \item[**]   $p < 0.05$,     
    \item[***]  $p < 0.01$
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: @James, here is policy that instead say `thank you` you vote for question (by clicking on up pen at the top left side of answer) and selected one of among received, which is the best way solve your problem :-)